# Geoserver(VPS) connection to PostgreSql(localhost)

Tags: postgresql, server, vps, geoserver

I am trying to connect Geoserver (installed in a VPS) to a PostgreSql database wich is running into my pc(localhost). I have follow the steps to allow this kind of connection(I do not know if all needed):

POSTGRESQL:

1.- Edit pg_hba.config of PostgreSql to allow Ip of VPS(Geoserver):

> `host    all        all             ip_VPS/24          md5`

2.- Edit postgresql.conf to allow remote connections:

> `listen_addresses ='*'`

WINDOWS:

1.- Firewall configuration to allow Ip(VPS) access.

,but i still getting this connection error:

> Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory
>   (Connection to My_Ip(pc):5432 refused. Check that the hostname and
>   port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP
>   connections.).

Would i have to make other configuration ?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0k. You have in pg_hba.config:

```
host    all        all             ip_VPS/24          md5
```

Maybe you should try this:

```
host    all        all             ip_VPS/24          trust
```

Then you should restart postgres.

(For the parameter "trust" or "md5" I recommend reviewing:

www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Greetings.